# Web worker is a process of browser or thread of browsers' process?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, browser, process

To code parallel programming in web browser by javascript, I could use web worker(browser web api).

During researching about these, I wonder whether web worker is process or thread.

Is it different from browser to browser? Web worker(Iframe..etc) is process in some browser and the others use as thread.

tell me about my asking please. :0

Comment: For parallel programming in browser, browser has a function. It's called web worker.

Comment: @Ivar web worker is a little different to other language worker.

Comment: @kuzyn You mean web worker could be process or thread?

Comment: All js stuff is single threaded isn't it? I dunno, have a look at the duplicate answers, it seems to explain how web workers work